# How to find the max number we can't calculate by given array?

Tags: python, arrays, sum

I have given a set of 4 numbers which I am able use at unlimited amouts. Is there a way to find the highest number that I can not calculate using that set?

I wonder if there is any mathematical formulas to calculate this kind of problems. I also have some basic python knowledge, so I am also curious about any approach using it.

I actually thougt a weird work around with my limited coding knowledge since i am not aware of the capabilities of Python.

For a test, I am thinking about creating an array of numbers starting from 0 zero to 1000000. After that i will try to calculate each number in this array with the given set of 4 numbers (11, 13, 17, 19). Each time there is an error while calculating i will print that number and that way i might be able to see the numbers we can't calculate.

---

*I don't know why people keep down voting question but the answer is 42. If you all those smarties can find a bigger one let me know then.*

Comment: I'm sorry, but your answer seems to be infinite. You'll always not be able to write a higher number with your base of numbers.

Comment: Unless you know the result beforehand, how would you know *which numbers you can't calculate* without actually calculating them?

Comment: This is really more of a math question than a software one. That said, there is no known closed form solution to the coin problem for `n >= 3`.

Comment: it's better to give us some sample of what you need at the end.

Comment: I have no idea how to solve this problem. Yes indeed it looks like a classic linear algebre problem. We have four prime numbers, which are 11, 13, 17, and 19; and we can use these numbers as much as we want. There are some obviously some numbers we cant calculate by these given numbers. For example we can get 33 by using 3 times only 11. We can get 35 with one 13 and two 11s. But these is no way we can calculate 34 with these four nubmers. And these are the only information i was given. I just wanted to integrate coding just because of my curiosity.

Comment: I have no idea why people downvoted this question but i think i explained my problem clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think

```
import itertools

myNumber=[]
myPerm=list(itertools.permutations([4, 12, 3]))
for item in myPerm:
    myNumber.append(int(''.join(str(e) for e in item)))
print(myNumber)
print(max(myNumber))
```

#### Result

```
myNumber=[4123, 4312, 1243, 1234, 3412, 3124]
max=4312
```

Comment: Actually this is not the problem i am trying to solve. The code should calculate the sum of the different combinations of numbers in that list. Like 4+12, 4+4+4, 3+3+12+12+4 etc. However since there is no limit for how many numbers that we can use for the calculation, question becomes quite different. Maybe there is something whong with the problem, i dont know, but this is what i was given.